# How to place a same image on the very top of every page of a section

Tags: graphics, positioning

I would like to place a same image on the very top of every page belonging to the *same* section of the document. Is that possible?

See the example below, where the figure is a PNG one:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section*{Section A}

\includegraphics{fig1}

A lot of contents spanning several pages. 

I would like to have the figure above repeated at the top of each page 
of Section A.

\section*{Section B}

\includegraphics{fig2}

A lot of contents spanning several pages. 

I would like to have the figure above repeated at the top of each page 
of Section B.

\end{document}
```

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

I have tried a different approach, by using `fancyhdr` package. (Please, see code below.) However, I am getting the problems that I show below. Any ideas?

PROBLEM 1

On the first page of the document.

[image]

PROBLEM 2

When returning to the plain style:

[image]

USED PICTURE

[image]

CODE I AM USING

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{logo}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[H]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{/tmp/x}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{logo}

\lipsum[1-8]

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{/tmp/x}

\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @KJO Thanks! Just added a minimal example.

Comment: @KJO Thanks! So let me ask the following: (1) Can your solution be adapted to emulate my second example, but without the problems I mentioned?; (2) Can one turn off inserting anything on the top of the page for certain and specified sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok have been playing with this and its just about a very minimal / basic solution. Version 1 (see later edits for V2 and V3 :-)

I had to borrow bits and pieces from several answers to get stable enough results however in Version 1 (based on section numbers) I broke one of your supplied requirements (the no numbers star in chapter/section definition)

I am working with each section having a number (which may not always be the case) and is contrary to your suppression to zero.

I am not allowing for right or left as such (I am assuming only right top corner) and if you want a section to be blank then you need a clear/blank image for the section. (However these points are addressed in version 2 later)

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,draft]{article}% use draft to observe numbering then remove for print run
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{everypage}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\number\value{section}}%
\newlength\Hoffset \Hoffset 0.0cm
\newlength\Voffset \Voffset 0.5cm
\AddEverypageHook{%
    \smash{\hspace{\oddsidemargin}\hspace{\textwidth}\hspace{\Hoffset}%
    \raisebox{\Voffset-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin}%
    {%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{example\thesection}
    }         }             }

\usepackage{lipsum} %remove after demo

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}% NOTe the star version will zero chapter counter thus blocking an image number

\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=9cm]{example\thesection}

A lot of contents spanning several pages. 
\newline
I would like to have the figure above repeated at the top of each page 
of Section A.
\lipsum[1-7]

\newpage % newpage is needed to split count from old section to new section
\section{Section B}
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=9cm]{example\thesection}

A lot of contents spanning several pages. 

I would like to have the figure above repeated at the top of each page 
of Section B.
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

### Version 2

The question was expanded to include some on/off control of headers and
I  was not happy with initial tying into section numbers (that might be suppressed). For version 2, I used fancy header based on the amended Question. However do note there are still some weaknesses in this method.

I have forced the normal fancy and plain header to be identical but the system will still treat chapter pages (and some others) as different so with this approach I can not assign logos to the first page of the chapter (not a problem if that has the full image and later pages just echo it.) There are many more ways we could expand our use of `fancyhdr` however since we are distorting the normal usage, the next level of customisation would best be achieved by say switching to a more dedicated overlay per page using dedicated on off markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{book} % I suspect LyX may be adding to and shuffling this preamble I set to book to show dual sided  abilities
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%--- just for the examples
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%---

\usepackage{fancyhdr,floatpag}
% globally remove fancy style rules since \pagestyle{plain} for chapters etc. = no header, and footer only contains page number centered
% set fancy to be similar default just have the page number
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}} % common method to use simple Bottom centre page numbers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% common method to blank (zero) the top header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\floatpagestyle{plain}% Page style for float-pages
%\usepackage[style=plain]{clrdblpg} this option will ensure verso pages are also plain

\fancypagestyle{logo}{%change LO,RE v RO,LE for opposite side or just C for centre
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\smash{\raisebox{0cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{x}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

%the following is a lyx construct so although not used I am leaving in place
\makeatletter 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % reset page number counter
\thispagestyle{logo}
\chapter{One}
\pagestyle{logo} %  If you want a fancy layout on a page containing \maketitle you must issue a \thispagestyle{fancy} after the \maketitle.
%\pagestyle{plain} % uncoment to reset
%
\lipsum[1-9]
\section{first still with logo}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{x.jpg}\newline\par\lipsum[10-12]
%
\newpage \pagestyle {plain} % if header style change is required it can usually be combined with \newpage at the same time
%\pagestyle{plain}
\section {without header image}
\noindent\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{x.jpg}%
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
Page style ``Plain'' default usually has only page number at bottom centre but no header.\newline\par
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

### Version 3 - not related to sections (uses current page for start stop)

This is one of many ways a watermark can be applied based on a very basic Bg NoBg (More complex methods of selecting pages are possible) so for more specific control choices read the `background` manual.
In this example I exclude "logo" on first and last page and use 50% opacity on all others.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[ %<===== Add to preamble
placement=top,
opacity=0.5]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{./tmp/x}}}

\makeatletter %<=====  Not needed here by TeX but as a LyX construct I am retaining for LyX users
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\makeatother %<=====  Not needed here by TeX but as a LyX construct I am retaining for LyX users

\usepackage{babel}

\pagestyle{fancy}% Change as you wish
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % Change as you wish
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% for example use only
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\NoBgThispage
Hello World my name is X

\noindent\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{./tmp/x}
\lipsum[1-8]
\BgThispage % we start logo on this page
\lipsum[1-7]
\NoBgThispage % we end logo this page
\end{document}
```

Comment: @K Thanks! Your solution works if one wants to have a picture for *every* section, and I would like to have a picture for only certain sections. Please, see the Supplement that I have added to my question.

Comment: @K Thanks! Your new solution seems to be what I need. Does it work with not numbered sections? My document does not have chapters, so that is OK. Will you share the LaTeX code?

Comment: @K Thanks! Your solution works almost fine! I find 2 problems: (1) With a different picture, a larger one, the whole picture is not shown on the header; (2) When a new section initiates in the middle of a page, its header overrides the header corresponding to the previous section (there is here a conflict, in which the previous section should have precedence over the current section).

Comment: @K Are you saying that it is possible to instruct LaTeX to put a picture on the top of specific pages? That is: Is it possible to tell LaTeX to put a picture on the top of pages 2 to 10, for instance? If that is possible, that would be a substitute solution to my problem!

Comment: @K That is it! Thanks for your help and patience!